# AdMob Keywords within AdWhirl (Android)

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl

Right now I am using Admob within AdWhirl.

As I understood from some forum AdWhirl does not give the keywords to Admob
also when in Adwhirl sdk its set like

```
            AdWhirlTargeting.setKeywords("keyword1 keyword2");
```

but someone mentioned (without demo) its still possible directly to set the password
by calling the AdMob Keyword function.

Does anyone can explain that to me so how to do so?

thx

Comment: here the link where its mentioned: http://groups.google.com/group/adwhirl-users/browse_thread/thread/3e4fd4003adff3d4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got now answers from AdMob also Google that AdMob does not support any
Keywords setting. "THEY MAY decide maybe in the future to do so !"